# Where can one view whether one has capital loss carryover from last year on one's tax forms from last year?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

I'm filing for my US taxes as a US lawful permanent resident, and I'm trying to determine whether I have any capital loss carryover from last year. Where I view this information somewhere in my tax forms from last year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For federal tax, look at the "Schedule D - Capital Gains and Losses" in the tax forms from last year:

- Schedule D, Line 07 for short-term;
- Schedule D, Line 15 for long-term;
- Schedule D, Line 16 for short-term + long-term. If the loss is greater than $3000 (or $1500 if MFS), you have carryover loss, else no.